# Windows Forms HelpButton Changes Cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a [HelpButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx) on a Windows Forms application.  When clicked, I just want it to show a message box.  This is working fine...

```
private void Form1_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is an awesome program", "Awesome Program");
}
```

The problem is, when the user closes out of the message box, the form cursor is switched to the "Help" cursor with the question mark on it.  This is not good.  How do I prevent the cursor from changing?  I tried putting `this.Cursor = Cursors.Default` and `this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow` after the message box call, but it was ineffective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your event handler declaration is incorrect, the `e` argument is actually of type CancelEventArgs.  Now it is simple:

```
    private void Form1_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("This is a more awesome program", "Awesome Program");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping you would see this question!  Mr. WinForms himself, thank you sir.

Comment: By the way, how do you auto-generate these declarations within the IDE, a la Visual Basic?

Comment: Lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Double-click the event name.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there had to be a way.

Comment: Just to add that you also need to register the event handler when you initialize the form, as follows: `this.HelpButtonClicked += Form1_HelpButtonClicked;` This threw me for awhile, as I'm usually a VB programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the HelpRequested event and set the Handled property of the event args to true, and don't bother handling the HelpButtonClicked event.

```
private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is an awesome program", "Awesome Program");
        hlpevent.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: No, that's not what I want because `HelpRequested` does not fire when the Help Button is clicked, it fires after you click another element on the form (after the cursor has already changed)

Comment: Right. I see it has been answered above.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the [Cursor.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current.aspx) static property.